# How to create check nested list for 2 tuples as a condition

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I have an assignment to program a simple tower defense game through printing, I'm having difficulties programming the defender units to attack and monster HP minuses. I'm trying to create a function to check each row for archr and zombi, if yes, then call the attack function and minus the monster HP, then move on to the next row

This is my current code and [and how my program should function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RY25.png)

```
import random

archer = {'shortform' : 'ARCHR',
          'name': 'Archer',
          'currentHP' : 5, 
          'maxHP': 5,
          'min_damage': 1,
          'max_damage': 4,
          'price': 5
          }

zombie = {'shortform': 'ZOMBI',
          'name': 'Zombie',
          'currentHP': 15,
          'maxHP': 15,
          'min_damage': 3,
          'max_damage': 6,
          'moves' : 1,
          'reward': 2
          }

field = [ [("ARCHR"," 5/5 "), None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None, None],
          [None, ("ARCHR"," 5/5 "), None, None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15")],
          [None, None, ("ARCHR"," 5/5 "), None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None],
          [None, ("ARCHR"," 5/5 "), None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None, None],
          [("ARCHR"," 5/5 "), None, None, None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15")] ]

num_rows=len(field)
num_columns=len(field[0])
row_abcde="ABCDE"

def draw_field(field):
    print(' {:^7}{:^5}{:^7}'.format('1','2','3'))
    
    print(' ',end='')
    for column in range(num_columns): 
        print('+-----',end='')
    print('+')

    for row in range(num_rows):
        print('{}'.format(row_indexes[row]), end='') # print row index
        for column in range(num_columns): #for each column,
            element = field[row][column]      
            if element is None:      #print spacings
                print('|     ' , end='') 
            else:                     #print monster name
                print('|' + element[0], end='')
        print('|') #end row

        print(' ', end='') #spacing for 2nd | row 
        for column in range(num_columns):
            element = field[row][column]
            if element is None:  #print spacing agn
                print('|     ' , end='')
            else:                     #print monster helth
                print('|' + element[1], end='')
        print('|') #end row

        print(' ', end='') #spacing for letter
        for column in range(num_columns):
            print('+-----', end = '')
        print('+')#end of row

    return field


def defender_attack(defender_name, field, row, column):
    damage= random.randint(1,4)
    print('{} in lane {} shoots {} for {} damage!'.format(defender_name['shortform'], row_indexes[row], element['shortform'], damage))
    element['currentHP'] -= damage
    if element['currentHP'] <= 0:
         print('someone died')
    element = None
    return

#start of code

draw_field(field) 

for row in field:
    if 'ARCHR' and 'ZOMBI' in row: #im trying to check the list for archr and zombi, but i know they're in a tuple, how should i do this?
        
        for column in row:
            element = field[row][column][0]      
            if element == 'ZOMBI':
                element = zombie
                print(element)
                defender_attack(archer,field,[row][column])

draw_field(field)
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Are your code not working at all, not working as intended, or you are stuck on how to implement a new feature? Please give us more details so we can understand your problem better!

Comment: Woops sorry if I wasn't clear, there's no error with the code but it's not working as intended, I want it to check row by row for an archer and zombie, and if yes, call the function to attack and minus hp from the zombie, but it seems my zombie's health isn't getting lowered and im not sure if the loop is working as intended too

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in field:
    isArch, isZombi = False, False
    for cell in row:
        if cell: 
            name, hp = cell
            if name == 'ARCHR': isArch = True
            elif name == 'ZOMBI': isZombi = True
    if isArch and isZombi:
        #do_something
```